# Where to store logged user information and menu name with Rights

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm using ASP.NET MVC and would like suggestions relating to managing user data and Menu Rights for View, Insert, Update and Delete for each menu.

There were two ways in my mind:

- Create Class for User Data an menu rights and then assign this object
  to  session
- Every time i will go to server and check user rights for each
  request.

I have a minimum of 1000 pages for User Rights and also 500 users logged in to the
system, so please let me know if there is a better scenario or give suggestions. Thanks.